# Fixing screen flicker / screen tearing

Tags: video, ffmpeg, obs

I had some capture issue in OBS, where during certain parts of my screen capture some windows flicker.

Here's a sample of the affected footage:

I think this should be at least to some degree correctable algorithmically, but I don't know the tools to implement that.

Basically for every pixel in the video stream I'd have to do this:

```
# we need to compare the same pixel in three consecutive frames

A = pixels[x,y, current_frame]
B = pixels[x,y, current_frame + 1]
C = pixels[x,y, current_frame + 2]

# if two border pixel values are identical, but the middle one is different - we assume that to be a flicker, so we replace the middle frame with the first one
if A == C and B != A:
   pixels[x,y, current_frame + 1] = pixels[x,y, current_frame]

# let's move onto the next frame
current_frame += 1
```

I wonder if this is possible to do with GLSL - I don't know if it has access to frame history...

Are there any (preferably free, open-source and running on Linux) tools that could do this?

Comment: ffmpeg could be made to do this, although your proposed method would not get rid of all flicker. If there's some screen activity/anim then A != C, and won't alter B even when B is defective. Also, in one or two cases, the tear lasts for more than one frame.

Comment: I've implemented this using Blender's Compositor - it seemed to help a bit for short clips, but I had trouble with A/V sync so I dropped the idea.
I'm including this in an answer however in case anyone wants to try this in their own projects.

I'd like to know more about the ffmpeg-based solution though, as that might be much faster to process (the Blender implementation was rather slow).

Answer (score 1):

**The propose algorithm can be implemented using Blender's Compositor.**

Here's a working project file:
https://is.gd/TeA4xC

You need to supply the same video file as input to three input nodes - each with a specified frame offset.

**This is capable of removing flickers that last no longer than 1 frame.**

I tried using this for my footage, but I had issues with A/V sync after remuxingthe result with the original audio, so I dropped the idea.

Here's how the example clip looks like after being processed with this file:

You can tell the flicker is much less pronounced. There are some artifacts, but they are way less distracting.

Hopefully someone will find this useful - I ultimately didn't :/

Enjoy.